# How can I get the IDs of all installed portlets in Liferay 6.2?

Tags: liferay-6

In Liferay *6.1* one could get the identifiers of installed portlets with `Liferay.Portlet.runtimePortletIds` or `WebKeys.RUNTIME_PORTLET_IDS`.

However in Liferay *6.2* this forms have disappeared.

Can anyone tell me a way to get the same results as with the methods discussed above in Liferay 6.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access nearly every model object in Liferay with a `...LocalServiceUtil`. In your case the `PortletLocalServiceUtil`:

```
List<Portlet> installedPortlets = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortlets();
for (Portlet installedPortlet : installedPortlets) {
  String portletId = installedPortlet.getPortletId();
  ...
}
```